# VBA lookup column based on cell contents

Tags: excel, vba

I used to have a table with a header row of 10 columns each labelled 1-10. I have combined some of the columns so that now my table looks like this.

| 0-2 | 3-4 | 5 | 6-7 | 8-9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Orange | Yellow | Green | Blue | Black |

Given a score of 5 I can use the following to find column C and get "Yellow":

```
Set range = Worksheets(colorScore).Range("1:1").Find(What:=Score)
```

But how can I extend that code to lookup a score of 3? or a score of 1?

Comment: Use `*` in the Score string

Comment: Use a helper row and `MATCH` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup with Intervals

- It is assumed that the range contains two rows where the first row contains the lookup value (whole number) or an interval of lookup values (whole numbers) and the second row contains the return values.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TESTlookupRowInterval()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = -5 To 15
        Result = lookupRowInterval(rg, i)
        If Not IsEmpty(Result) Then
            Debug.Print i, Result
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

' Result
' 0             Red
' 1             Red
' 2             Red
' 3             Orange
' 4             Orange
' 5             Yellow
' 6             Green
' 7             Green
' 8             Blue
' 9             Blue
' 10            Black

Function lookupRowInterval( _
    rg As Range, _
    ByVal LookupIndex As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = "-") _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If rg.Rows.Count <> 2 Then Exit Function
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim cInterval() As String
        Dim j As Long
        Dim n As Long
        Dim iStart As Long
        Dim iEnd As Long
        Dim iTemp As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            cInterval = Split(Data(1, j), Delimiter)
            Select Case UBound(cInterval)
                Case 0
                    If isLng(cInterval(0)) Then
                        .Item(CLng(cInterval(0))) = Data(2, j)
                    End If
                Case 1
                    If isLng(cInterval(0)) And isLng(cInterval(1)) Then
                        iStart = CLng(cInterval(0))
                        iEnd = CLng(cInterval(1))
                        If iStart > iEnd Then ' Switch.
                            iTemp = iStart: iStart = iEnd: iEnd = iTemp
                        End If
                        For n = iStart To iEnd
                            .Item(n) = Data(2, j)
                        Next n
                    End If
            End Select
        Next j
        If .Count = 0  Then Exit Function
        lookupRowInterval = .Item(LookupIndex)
    End With
End Function

Function isLng( _
    CheckValue As Variant) _
As Boolean
    On Error GoTo clearError
    Dim Result As Long
    If UBound(Split(CheckValue, ".")) = 0 Then ' Allow only whole numbers.
        Result = CLng(CheckValue) ' Error if not number.
        isLng = True
    End If
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim numCols As Integer
Dim isRng As String
Dim colHeading As String
Dim lowNum As String
Dim highNum As String
Dim num As String

'Count the number of title row cells
numCols = Worksheets(trait).Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
For i = 1 To numCols
    colHeading = Worksheets(trait).Cells(1, i).Value
    isRng = InStr(colHeading, "-") 'does it have a dash (is it a range)?
    If isRng Then 'if it does have a dash...
        lowNum = Mid(colHeading, 1, isRng - 1) 'everything before the dash
        highNum = Mid(colHeading, isRng + 1) 'everything after the dash
        If score >= lowNum And score <= highNum Then 'if your score is between or equal to the low and high numbers...
            Debug.Print "Your score come from column " & i
        End If
    Else 'if it doesn't have a dash...
        num = colHeading
        If score = num Then
            Debug.Print "Your score come from column " & i
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ReturnColor(number As Integer) As String
    Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Rows(1), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    ReturnColor = "#no match#"
    For Each cl In Rng
        a = Split(cl, "-")
        Select Case True
            Case number < CInt(a(0))
                Exit For
            Case number = a(0)
                ReturnColor = cl.Offset(1): Exit For
            Case UBound(a) = 1
                If number <= CInt(a(1)) Then ReturnColor = cl.Offset(1): Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = -5 To 15
        Debug.Print "Color for " & i & " is " & ReturnColor(i)
    Next
End Sub
```